# why do i have errors inside my subscribe?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I work on an e-commerce site and I have errors in my "cartservice" and in particular on my "checkoutFromCart ()" function, the error that the console displays is as follows:

src/app/services/cart.service.ts:218:81
218       this.http.post(`${this.serverUrl}orders/payment`, null).subscribe((res: { success: boolean }) => {
~~~~~~~
'success' is declared here.

Error: src/app/services/cart.service.ts:228:24 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: NextObserver | ErrorObserver | CompletionObserver | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(data: orderResponse) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextObserver | ErrorObserver | CompletionObserver | undefined'.
Property 'complete' is missing in type '(data: orderResponse) => void' but required in type 'CompletionObserver'.
Overload 2 of 5, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(data: orderResponse) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are incompatible.
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'orderResponse': order_id, success, message, products

228           }).subscribe((data:orderResponse) => {
[91m                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts:73:5
73     complete: () => void;
~~~~~~~~
'complete' is declared here.

my code:
[checkoutFonction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsstj.png)

console error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btC5f.png)

I'm sorry if the question is wrong to ask I'm starting on stackoverflow but please I need help

I'm sorry for the images here is the code:

CheckoutFromCart(userId: number) {

```
  this.http.post(`${this.serverUrl}orders/payment`, null).subscribe((res:{ success: boolean }) => {
    console.clear();

    if (res.success) {


      this.resetServerData();
      this.http.post(`${this.serverUrl}orders/new`, {
        userId: userId,
        products: this.cartDataClient.prodData
      }).subscribe((data:orderResponse) => {

        this.orderservice.getSingleOrder(data.order_id).then(prods => {
          if (data.success) {
            const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
              state: {
                message: data.message,
                products: prods,
                orderId: data.order_id,
                total: this.cartDataClient.total
              }
            };
            this.router.navigate(['/thankyou'], navigationExtras).then(p => {
              this.cartDataClient = {prodData: [{incart: 0, id: 0}], total: 0};
              this.cartTotal$.next(0);
              localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this.cartDataClient));
            });
          }
        });

      })
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/checkout').then();
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: getSingleOrder is a Promise or an observable? BTW you can use rxjs operator `switchMap` or another to "concat" observables

Comment: Try not to post images of code, rather just paste the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the return type in your post methods like this:

```
this.http.post<{success: boolean}>().subscr...
```

and

```
this.http.post<orderResponse>().subscr...
```